# itertools group by multiple keys

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am using `itertools` to `group by` a `dictionary key` using the below:

```
host_data = []
for k,v in itertools.groupby(temp_data, key=lambda x:x['device_id'])
    d = {}
    for dct in v:
        d.update(dct)
    host_data.append(d)
```

However I would like to group by 'device_id' and 'port_id' if possible, how can I add an additional key to the grouping?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use a tuple as key:

```
itertools.groupby(temp_data, key=lambda x:(x['device_id'], x['port_id']))
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the key a tuple: `key=lambda x: (x['device_id'], x['port_id'])`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to make a 2-tuple grouping key:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
...
itertools.groupby(temp_data, key=itemgetter('device_id', 'port_id'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand a little bit on the accepted answer:

Once you use a tuple as a grouping key, you can retrieve the tuple values when iterating the grouped data, in case you need it, e.g.:

```py
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    {"device_id": 1, "port_id": 1, "some_value": 1},
    {"device_id": 1, "port_id": 2, "some_value": 2},
    {"device_id": 1, "port_id": 2, "some_value": 3},
    {"device_id": 2, "port_id": 1, "some_value": 1},
    {"device_id": 2, "port_id": 1, "some_value": 2},
    {"device_id": 3, "port_id": 1, "some_value": 1},
]

grouped_data = groupby(data, key=lambda x: (x["device_id"], x["port_id"]))

for (device_id, port_id), group in grouped_data:
    print(f"device_id, port_id: {device_id}, {port_id}")
    print(f"  -> group: {list(group)}")
```

which would print:

```
device_id, port_id: 1, 1
  -> group: [{'device_id': 1, 'port_id': 1, 'some_value': 1}]
device_id, port_id: 1, 2
  -> group: [{'device_id': 1, 'port_id': 2, 'some_value': 2}, {'device_id': 1, 'port_id': 2, 'some_value': 3}]
device_id, port_id: 2, 1
  -> group: [{'device_id': 2, 'port_id': 1, 'some_value': 1}, {'device_id': 2, 'port_id': 1, 'some_value': 2}]
device_id, port_id: 3, 1
  -> group: [{'device_id': 3, 'port_id': 1, 'some_value': 1}]
```